# SetExcelDocumentProperties not in Output Selector VS2015/ISLE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vsto, installshield-le

In previous versions of Visual Studio (2013 and below from what I can tell on [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx):)

> In the Application Files page, choose the **Add Project Outputs** button.
>   The **Visual Studio Output Selector** dialog box appears.
>   Under the **SetExcelDocumentProperties node**, select the Primary Output check box, and then choose the OK button.

In Visual Studio 2015 / Install Shield Limited Edition the **Visual Studio Output Selector** only shows this dialog box:

[image]

I dont have any lower versions of VS to verify but if they have dropped this, what is the equivalent now.

I am trying to setup a VSTO installer for a 64 Bit Excel Add In.